# How to integrate customer's Azure Active Directory with your SAAS platform?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, integration, saas

We have a SAAS platform deployed on AWS with our own identity manager. Our customer wants us to use their on-prem Azure AD to allow users to authenticate on our web and mobile application instead of users creating a separate account in our platform. Do we deploy an agent on-prem that authenticates the user on their AD and gives us a pass/fail and sync the users to our ID manager for our own authentication? What changes we need to do in our platform and what changes need to happen at the customer end? What products we need to use to implement this feature? I am trying to understand what will be the workflow to accomplish this. Our platform in built on .net core with REST APIs and using web/mobile front ends.

Appreciate any help I can get. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using oAuth with AAD.

Also, there is no such thing as Azure AD on-prem. Azure AD is hosted in Azure. They may have a AD connector that syncs their AD to Azure AD, but Azure AD is always in the azure "cloud."

[Protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory and API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)
[Secure a Restful service in your Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api)